# Core Data get B objects from A object where B.cObjects is nil

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data object A.

Object A contains an array of objects B - like `A.bObjects`. 
Object B contains an array of objects C - like `B.cObjects`.

How can I get all objects B from object A where `B.cObjects` is nil?

I can work around this like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(B *b in A.bObjects)
{
    if([b.cObjects count] == 0)
        [array addObject:b];
}
```

But i think it will take a lot of resources if I would have a lot of objects B. And I do not like my workaround.:)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could use, if you just want all the Bs from a particular A that have empty cObjects.

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"cObjects.@count == 0"];
NSArray* emptyCObjects = [A.bObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

If you want all the Bs from all of the As that have empty cObjects, combine that with a NSFetchRequest.

Not a 100% sure which would be more effective, but if I were to hazard a guess, I would say use predicates and KVC as I believe Apple has made some optimisations under the hood. Also its fewer lines of code whi

Comment: Thank you very much. In my case you forget about filtering by object A. So in my case predicate will be: NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(self.A == %@) and (cObjects.@count == 0)", A];

Comment: I am filtering A.bObjects using that predicate so it should produce the same results as your code.

Comment: Now I see. Yep, your solution better. Thank you.